# background-color property not working on Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

Im workin on this site https://www.comercialoregon.cl and realized that when on Safari, some elements will not properly display, the main ones being those with the background-color property set to #11a004e0, instead they have a gray background. any ideas why this happening?

Here is the css for the div on the nav bar that SHOULD be green (works on chrome and mozilla). Thanks

```
.boton_nav {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #11a004e0;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 220px;
  margin-left: 2em;
  animation-name: boton_nav;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
```

Comment: maybe safari doens't support the 4 Hex code color .. use rgba instead

Answer (score 1):

> This server could not prove that it is www.comercialoregon.cl; its
>   security certificate expired 428 days ago.

There's your first problem, but it isn't directly related to the question. Just felt like reminding you that your visitors will first see that big scary invalid certificate screen and will likely leave.

---

The issue is you are using the #rrggbbaa hexadecimal colour notation which is not yet widely supported. As of now, [according to caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-rrggbbaa), only Firefox, Chrome and Safari support it. I know you mentioned it's not working on Safari, but perhaps you're on a version older than 10?

Regardless, support isn't good so I wouldn't recommend using it just yet. Instead, use the `rgba` function. `background-color: #11a004e0;` would become `background-color: rgba(17, 160, 4, 224);` as the colour values are represented in decimal rather than hexadecimal.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. Regarding your first comment, I didnt realize that, thanks for noting it, any pointer to how I could fix the expired certificate?

Comment: @papafrita Well, your HTTPS URL seems to redirect to HTTP so make sure the redirect is the other way 'round if you do fix your certificate. The solution for the expired certificate is to renew it. I noticed your certificate was valid for three months and was issued by cPanel. I'm not too savvy with these things but that's the same length of time Let's Encrypt certificates are valid for. If it was free, just log on and renew it however you did so in the first place. Ideally it should be renewing automatically though.